# Issue installing VIB on ESXi 6.5U1

Tags: vmware-esxi

Running ESXi 6.5U1.
Trying to install OMSA from cli.

When I run:

```
esxcli software vib install -d "vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ISOs/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-9.1.0-3523.VIB-ESX60i_A00 (2).zip"
```

I have confirmed that the file "vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ISOs/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-9.1.0-3523.VIB-ESX60i_A00 (2).zip" does exist and that it has an index.xml inside.

I get the following result:

> [MetadataDownloadError]  Could not download from depot at
>   zip:/var/log/vmware/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ISOs/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-9.1.0-3523.VIB-ESX60i_A00
>   (2).zip?index.xml, skipping
>   (('zip:/var/log/vmware/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ISOs/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-9.1.0-3523.VIB-ESX60i_A00
>   (2).zip?index.xml', '', "Error extracting index.xml from
>   /var/log/vmware/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ISOs/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-9.1.0-3523.VIB-ESX60i_A00
>   (2).zip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/var/log/vmware/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ISOs/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-9.1.0-3523.VIB-ESX60i_A00
>   (2).zip'"))
>           url = zip:/var/log/vmware/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ISOs/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-9.1.0-3523.VIB-ESX60i_A00
>   (2).zip?index.xml

For some reason esxcli is prepending the "/var/log/vmware" in front of the zip location.

I did nook in the logs but am not sure which log would give me the right info. In any case I did not find any helpful info.

I am new to vib's. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use the absolute path to your zip file. It's [even documented](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.upgrade.doc/GUID-1E773360-CB1C-4BC2-B2A4-B73AB5706FAF.html):

> ```
> esxcli --server=server_name software sources vib list --depot=absolute_path_to_depot_zip_file
> ```

In your case:

```
esxcli software vib install -d "/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ISOs/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-9.1.0-3523.VIB-ESX60i_A00 (2).zip"
```

Note the missing `/` at the start of your path.

Comment: I am such a dumb A**. Thank you.